# pandas groupby aggregate ignoring blank or none values

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am new to python and pandas. How can we apply a groupby and an aggregate on multiple columns ignoring the blank/None/NaN values? 
Basically, i want to aggregate columns over date and take count of the remaining columns ignoring the None/blank/NaN values.

EXAMPLE:
I have the data like:

```
    ID  Ra  out recommen    navi    Time
0   1   7   None    None    NaN 2013-11-11
1   2   1   None    None    3   2013-11-11
2   5   5   None    None    1   2013-11-12
3   6   9   None    None    NaN 2013-11-12
4   9   2   None    None    NaN 2013-11-12
5   10  10  None    None    NaN 2013-11-12
6   11  10  None    None    NaN 2013-11-12
7   12  10  None    None    NaN 2013-11-12
8   13  5   None    None    NaN 2013-11-12
```

I am trying to apply a groupby and count agregation function on these values as:
    daily=df.groupby('Time').count()

**This gives me:**

```
ID  Ra  out recommen    navi    Time
2   2   2   2           2       2013-11-11
7   7   7   7           7       2013-11-12
```

**Expected output is:**

```
ID  Ra  out recommen    navi    Time
2   0   0   0           1       2013-11-11
7   0   0   0           1       2013-11-12
```

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use the method dropna()

Read the documentation for further information: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

In advance, use your id column as index, instead.

You can do the following:

```
df = df.set_index(df["ID"])
```

Documentation -> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html